Databricks - Requested array size exceeding vm limit
I am getting error "requested array size exceeding vm limit" when loading only one record and one column from SQL server using spark jdbc.
I know this issue due to huge column,having around 1 billion characters in it.but still that size around 1.5 gb i do allocated the executor memory to 100gb why I am still getting this out of memory error in spark?
Does spark have any limitations on charcter length?
Is there any other approach is there in databricks to load the data?
Need a help on loading this data to adls

similar to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78607892/1028537 it's due to byte[] maximum lengths and character encoding.  2gb in total for any string or byte array, and worse, two gb in total for any row (which is a byte array).
Given you'll hit the row limit you need to move it to a file and reference that (from a centrally accessible place) or leave it in the SQL Server and have a rowid reference or similar.

Thankyou. Why can't spark handle that data while SQL server able to handle it?

Unless it chains it'd be stuck with a similar limitation for strings, the docs seem to hint that it is.  The difference, as noted in the link I gave, is that the jvm itself changed what can be stored in later jdks.  Perhaps you can try running on jdk 8?
